# All option for top and bottom pager control

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I use the below code to apply "all" option in pager dropdown. This is only apply for bottom pager only not for top bar. Please help me to apply this for both top and bottom pager

```
rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 1000, 10000000],
pager: '#pager


$("#pager option[value=10000000]").text('All');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us you have grid with `id="list"` for example, then the id of the toppager will be `list_toppager`. So to change "10000000" text in both pagers you can do the following

```js
$("#pager .ui-pg-selbox option[value=10000000]").text("All");
$("#list_toppager .ui-pg-selbox option[value=10000000]").text("All");
```

or alternatively you can use one line

```js
$("#list").closest(".ui-jqgrid")
    .find(".ui-pg-selbox option[value=10000000]")
    .text("All");
```

which changes text in both top and bottom pagers.